# Exporting std::map as object instead of dict with pybind

Tags: python, c++, stdmap, pybind11

With pybind11, C++ `std::map` objects can be mapped to/from Python `dict` objects like:

```
struct A {
    std::map<std::string, int> attributes;

    A() { attributes["x"] = 1; attributes["y"] = 2; }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(Example, m) {
    py::class_<A>(m, "A")
        .def_readonly("attributes", &A::attributes)
}
```

can be accessed in Python as:

```
a.attributes["x"]
a.attributes["y"]
```

---

Is it possible to instead set pybind to map it such that the elements of the `std::map` become attributes of the `a` object on Python, that can be accessed using dot syntax, like:

```
a.attributes.x
a.attributes.y
```

Comment: Rough idea: bind `std::map` to [opaque types](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types) which has [dynamic attributes](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html#dynamic-attributes), and maintain the states of member `attributes` and `__dict__`. (overloading  `__setattr__` / `__getattr__` somehow).

Comment: Since `__dict__` is already a dict, maintaining a internal `std::map` seems a duplication?